# функция конструктор для скрытия/показа текста

Tags: javascript

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showHide(element_id) {
    if (document.getElementById(element_id)) { 
      var obj = document.getElementById(element_id);  
      if (obj.style.display != "block") { 
        obj.style.display = "block"; 
      } else obj.style.display = "none";
    }
  }   
</script>
 

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showHide('block_id')">Скрыть/Показать элемент</a><br/><br/>
<div id="block_id" style="display: none;">
    Тут любой текст и html код<br/>
    <br/>
    Дизайн студия OX2 разрабатывает сайты и интернет магазины любой сложности. <br/>
    По низким ценам! 
</div>
```

реализовал обычной функцией, как из нее сделать конструктор? заранее благодарен.

Comment: а главное "Дизайн студия OX2 разрабатывает сайты и интернет магазины любой сложности."

Comment: да это просто пример из интернета

Comment: уже можно просто в  main.js(или где у вас там) писать showHide('ваш ид'); без он клик на элементы

Comment: конструктор чего?, можете конкретнее сформулировать задачу?

Comment: конструктор реализации сайтов под ключ по низким ценам:DDD

Comment: функцию конструктор для скрытия показа текста, как простой функцией сделать знаю, как из нее сделать конструктор нет...

Comment: Frank Sinatra, поглумиться можешь в другом месте

Comment: ты по сути сделал "конструктор" и как пользоваться я написал выше

Comment: если я прав, то конструктор создается с помощью ключевого слова new, у меня его нет

Comment: @lesha310392, а зачем? как разница?

Comment: я хочу потом реализовать наследника потом который будет скрывать плавно

Comment: в таком случае - никак. Так как эта функция просто выполняет действие и не хранит состояние - использование ее в качестве конструктора ничего не даст и не будет никакой разницы. не говоря о том, что от нее будет проблематично наследоваться для изменения поведения, так как поведение описано в самом конструкторе

Comment: тогда можете подсказать как реализовать?

Comment: _если я прав, то конструктор создается с помощью ключевого слова new_ - нет ты не прав, конструктором может выступать почти любая функция. new не создает конструктор, он _вызывает_ функцию как конструктор

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46496/discussion-between-grundy-and-lesha310392).

Comment: сделал всем спасибо, за помощь.

Comment: function ShowHide(obj) {
            this.obj = obj;
            this.visibility = function () {
                if (obj.style.display != "block") { 
                    obj.style.display = "block"; 
                }else {
                    obj.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                }
            };

        var obj = document.getElementById('block_id'); 
        var constr = new ShowHide( obj );